# jQuery click event not firing for dialog button

Tags: jquery

I've login form as shown below,

```
<a href="#" id="loginLink">click Here to Log in</a>
<div class="formDiv" id="formDiv">
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="#">
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
    <label>Passw</label><input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="loginbtn" name="loginbtn">
</form>
</div>
```

I want to submit this form data using `Ajax`,for that when user clicks on `#loginbtn` I'm  doing Ajax related stuff,but the trouble is `click` event not firing when clicks on `#loginbtn`,here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNMfA/) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the div which holds the dialog is dynamically added, you cannot bind click event to it. Bind it instead to some parent which is fixed like `document`.

I have edited the fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/WNMfA/2/

Comment: Its worked for me but jQuery validations are doing can you look at this http://jsfiddle.net/WNMfA/3/.

Comment: You have not written the `validate()` function in the fiddle

Comment: you have called `validate()` but not defined it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to bind the click event like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#loginbtn",function(e){
// do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could create buttons within the dialog definition as in

```
 $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Login": function() {
        alert('test');
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  }
});
```